# Extension of isometries on submanifolds of a riemannian manifold

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ be a submanifold of a Riemannian manifold $M$. Suppose that the closure of $S$ is equal $M$, i.e, $\bar{S}=M$.

When can we extend an isometry (as Riemannian manifold) $f:S\to S$ to an isometry $\tilde{f}:M\to M$?

Comment: By an isometry do you mean isometry as a metric space?

Comment: No, I mean that with isometry in the riemannian sense, i.e. the diferential preserve the riemannian metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a partial answer, mainly intended to point out a class of counterexamples.**

**1.** If "isometry" means that $f : S \to S$ preserves the metric in the sense that $d_M(f(x), f(y)) = d_M(x,y)$ for points $x,y \in S$, then it seems that all you need is the assumption that $M$ is complete. In this case, of course, there's no need to assume that $S$ is a submanifold.

**2.** On the other hand, you may mean for $S$ to be an immersed submanifold and $f$ to be preserving the Riemannian metric on $S$ given by pulling back the Riemannian metric on $M$ via the inclusion. In this case I do not have a definite condition on $S$ for there to exist such an extension, but I suspect that it is rare.

As a large class of counterexamples to possible conjectures one might make, consider any Riemannian manifold $M$ satisfying the conditions:

(a) $M$ has a geodesic $\gamma$ whose orbit is dense; and

(b) $M$ has finite isometry group.

We take $S$ to be the submanifold given by the orbit of $\gamma$; there is a one-parameter family $\phi_a$ of orientation-preserving isometries of $S$ given by $\phi_a : \gamma(t) \mapsto \gamma(t + a)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. These isometries are distinct on $S$. Since $M$ has finite isometry group, most of these isometries cannot come from restrictions of isometries of $M$.

Every closed hyperbolic surface satisfies (a) and (b), so such manifolds definitely exist.

In any case, any condition we impose on $S$ or $M$ to try to get our conclusion will have to exclude such examples; no such natural condition comes to my mind, but maybe others will have more success.

Comment: I've thought  about the item 2. My question was born when I've tried extend an isometry without isolated points, in this case $S=M- \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$. If $M$ is complete the answer is true, because any isometry as riemannian manifold  of $S$ is too an isometry as metric space,  for item 1 we have $f:M\to M$  an isometry as metric space,but if you have an isometry as metric space,  then $f$ is an isometric in the riemannian sense, for see this we need use some arguments of distance functions (see Petersen, Riemannian Geometry).

Comment: Isometry on differential level is not enough to give isometry of metric space. For example, take $M = \mathbb R^2$, $S = \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{y=0\}$ and define $f(x, y) = ( x +\text{sign} (y), y)$. It's an isometry in the sense of (2) but not an isometry on metric space. @Melo.M.M

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about a wronger reciprocal of Myers-Steenrod  theorem :

If $(M,g)$ and $(N,\bar{g})$ are Riemannian
manifolds and $F: M → N$ a bijection, then $F$ is a Riemannian isometry if $F$ is
distance-preserving, i.e., $\bar{d}(F(p), F(q)) = dg (p, q)$ for all $p, q \in M$.

Comment: @Melo.M.M In the case $S = M \setminus \lbrace p_1, \dots, p_n \rbrace$, as long as the dimension of $M$ is at least $2$, the distance function $S$ gets from its inherited Riemannian structure agrees with the distance function it gets as a subset of the metric space $M$. (Given $p, q \in S$, take a path that approximates the distance between them; you can perturb it to not run through any of the $p_i$.) Thus by (1) Riemannian isometries of $S$ extend to $M$. (I wonder if it is always true for $S$ open, connected, and dense -- I can't come up with a proof or counterexample for this conjecture.)

Comment: @mollyerin yours conjecture is in some sense what i hoped about this problem. I'll think more about... Thanks for comment!

Comment: Right, you do not even need the curve $\gamma$ to be geodesic, any smooth curve with arc-length parameterization would suffice. You do not need $M$ to have a finite isometry group: If $\gamma$ is dense and is not the entire $M$ then a nontrivial translation of $\gamma$ never extends to an isometry of $M$.